# validation rule for not changing a field by Quote status Closed Won besides the Admin profile

Tags: validation-rule, quote

Good day, 
I have to create a validation rule that will prevent all users for changing of the field Account on Quote object when the Quote Status is closed won. 
Here is my validation rule, and it is working as expected:

```
AND (
    ISPICKVAL( SBQQ__Status__c ,"Closed Won") ,
    ISCHANGED( SBQQ__Account__c ) 
)
```

The additional condition is bypass the validation rule for Admin profile (without Bypass validation flag). Could somebody support me in this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the profile.Name condition as below.

```
AND (
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
ISPICKVAL( SBQQ__Status__c ,"Closed Won") ,
ISCHANGED( SBQQ__Account__c ) )
```